# Auto-aim in the PC version

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

In Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas on PS2 you have an option to automatically aim at people. That or it was default, but alongside it you could manually aim. In the PC version, I can't seem to auto aim, only manually aiming. Is there any way to turn this on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to auto aim in a PC version is to use a joypad/controller setup instead of the keyboard/mouse setup. You can set the controller configuration to joypad and use the keyboard for it, but then you won't be able to use the mouse.

Comment: Are there no mods or anything to do so?

Comment: @SimonSheehan I edited my answer to show one that I found, although I have no experience with it so I don't know how useful it is.

Comment: The file host link is down.

Comment: Removed link to the mod as the link isn't working and I don't know enough to find anything new.